# Commutative property of summed formulas

Tags: functions

I hope those more skilled in math than I am can help me understand. Given this formula:

x - y = z

Because subtraction is involved, the left-hand cannot be commutative. But when we sum other calculations together:

x<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>1</sub> = z<sub>1</sub>

x<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>2</sub> = z<sub>2</sub>

...

x<sub>n</sub> - y<sub>n</sub> = z<sub>n</sub>

=> Σx - Σy = Σz

This still holds at least in small experiments I've tried. But few experiments doesn't constitute a proof and it feels unintuitive that the total of the formula would be still commutative even if it contains non-commutative operators.

Put it other way, it doesn't matter if I sum all x's and y's or if I first calculate the individual z's then sum the z's up; either method arrive to the same Σz, in spite of a subtraction being performed. Why?

Comment: The subtraction doesn't utterly destroy commutativity, in fact it's anticommutative: $y-x=-(x-y)$, which is in some sense failure in the best possible way. All of this can be resolved easily however, hopefully even to your satisfaction, by writing $x+(-y)=z$, turning everything into addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this; @Matt Samuel's explanation in the comment to the original question was sufficient, namely by rewriting the equation to:

x + (-y) = z

which then is obviously commutative since it's additions all around. Thanks!